# Finding minimum of several integers

Tags: c#

In a program that requires the user to input the number of integers, I cannot find out how to display the minimum of all the values.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("\n Number of values:");
  int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  int[] number = new int[num];

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("\n Enter value:");
    number[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  }




  for (i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
  {
    int Min = number[0];

    if (number[i + 1] < Min)
    {
      Min = number[i + 1];
    }
  }


  Console.WriteLine("Smallest is {0}", Min);


}
```

Comment: Try moving `Min` *outside* your loop... (And rename it to `min`, and consider using LINQ instead...)

Answer (score 5):

Declare `Min` outside for loop

```
int Min = number[0];

for (i = 1; i < number.Length; i++)
{
    if (number[i] < Min)
    {
        Min = number[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are methods that do this for you:

```
int[] number = new int[num];

int min = number.Min();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
int minNumber = numbers.Min();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Min`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to calculate this.

```
int min = number.Min();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int FindMinimum(int[] values)
{
    int result = int.MaxValue;

    foreach (int value in values)
        result = Math.Min(result, value);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code will overflow the array.  You should check index 0 first and then check the rest.

Replace

```
for (i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
{
   int Min = number[0];

   if (number[i + 1] < Min)
   {
       Min = number[i + 1];
   }
}
```

with

```
int Min = number[0];

for (i = 1; i < number.Length; i++)
{   
    if (number[i] < Min)
    {
        Min = number[i];
    }
}
```

However, you could simply use [Enumerable.Min()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548864%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as `int Min = number.Min(x => x)`

Answer (score 1):

how about this?!

```
int[] Numbers = new int[5] { 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 15 };
var q = (from Num in Numbers
         select Num).Min();
```

Have a look at LINQ samples from MSDN: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Why not simply `Numbers.Min()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use linq to object.

1. use Min method
2. sort your data in descending and take the first one

Comment: you have several ways ... i my self using Min function on list it's the simplest

Answer (score 0):

- Declare Min as global static for example - public static int Min
- Change the loop condition to  for (i = 0; i < number.Length -1 ; i++) you exceed by one index range
- Put Console.ReadLine on the end.

Or you don't have to store all numbers

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int min = int.MaxValue;

    Console.WriteLine("\n Number of values:");
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    var enteredValue = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n Enter value:");
        enteredValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (min>enteredValue) min = enteredValue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Smallest is {0}", min);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```